# How to stop Chrome from reloading pinned tabs non-stop, then any other tab I click on (Win7)?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, gmail, tabs

Finding no other relevant answer here, can someone please advise me on the following problem:

Intermittently (about daily) when I try to start Chrome at least one pinned tab continues reloading(usually a Gmail tab). When I close the tab or try another pinned tab then that one tries to reload too, becoming unusable, and showing circled "i" in URL line (in place of Secure padlock) indicating site insecure. (Gmail still OK on Firefox and on Kindle Fire), so I think it's a Chrome problem.

I've tried everything from checking settings closing excess tabs, clearing history, running c-cleaner (after some of these Chrome has settled down once, but not on subsequent occasions), restarting Chrome, running malwarebytes and Symantec A-V, restarting the WIN7 PC, to reinstalling the latest chrome.

Eventually it settles down, sometimes after one of the above steps, or. more recently, the Nth attempt to open a bookmarked page, but it wastes about 20-30 minutes of my day, most days.

Advice appreciated - but feel free to ask for more detail if needed, please.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By good fortune, I've found an answer to my question - but I'm leaving it up here as I can see by googling the following combination "malwarebytes chrome secure preferences" that other people have had the same problem.

Recent versions of MalwareBytes identify, as a PUP, the Secure Preferences file (in System Profile(C:Users\ [XXX=YOUR ID]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data)).

This became clear when I quarantined this PUP and noticed Chrome crashed immediately. **Quarantining this file is the cause of the problem posted in the above Question.**

I therefore went back into malwarebytes, released the quarantined item and reloaded Chrome. A short while later it was working again.

Here's [an explanation of possible full solutions to avoiding this problem altogether](https://positek.net/malwarebytes-hates-chrome/). although I shall, for the moment, merely not delete this PUP when MalWareBytes locates it.